# Is there a way to use TransactionScope with an existing connection?

Tags: c#, transactions, transactionscope

I have some code that works like the advised use of TransactionScope, but has an ambient connection instead of an ambient transaction.

Is there a way to use a TransactionScope object with an existing connection, or is there an alternative in the .Net framework for this purpose?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In fact, there is one way.

```
connection.EnlistTransaction(Transaction.Current)
```

It works and it doesnt promote transaction to distributed if not necessary (contrary to what documentation says)

HTH

Comment: what is `connection` ?

Comment: Just any class derived from [DbConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbconnection?view=netframework-4.8#methods)

Answer (score 5):

To enlist a connection into a TransactionScope, you need to specify `'Enlist=true'` in its connection string and open the connection in the scope of that TransactionScope object.

You can use  `SqlConnection.BeginTransaction` on an existing connection.

**Update**: Can you use `BeginTransaction` like this:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    SqlTransaction transaction;

    // Start a local transaction.
    transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction");

    // Must assign both transaction object and connection
    // to Command object for a pending local transaction
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.Transaction = transaction;

    ...
    ...

}
```

Comment: The thing is, the connection is opened in advance of the TransactionScope instantiation; hence the reason for my question.

Comment: @Mitch, Doesn't the connection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction") promote to a Distributed Transaction (DTC) in any scenario? If it does, then what are those scenarios?

Answer (score 3):

After more research, the answer to my question turned out to be:

No, the connection needs to be opened after the TransactionScope object is instantiated.